# Redirect 301 with percentage mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to perform the following redirection in .htaccess file, but I can not make them work. Can you help me?

Redirect is this:

```
https://www.example.com/example/CL%C3%81SULA%20DE%20MUERTE%20ACCIDENTAL%20CAD220130535.pdf to https://www.example.com/example-cl/images/example.pdf
```

I tried this:

```
Redirect 301 "/example/CL%C3%81SULA%20DE%20MUERTE%20ACCIDENTAL%20CAD220130535.pdf" https://www.example.com/example-cl/images/example.pdf
```

Thank you very much. Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess (a level above `/example/`):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^example/CL\xC3\x81SULA\x20DE\x20MUERTE\x20ACCIDENTAL\x20CAD220130535\.pdf$ /example-cl/images/example.pdf [L,R=302]
```

This is assuming `/example/.htaccess` doesn't exist. If you already have `/example/.htaccess` then use this rule as **very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^CL\xC3\x81SULA\x20DE\x20MUERTE\x20ACCIDENTAL\x20CAD220130535\.pdf$ /example-cl/images/example.pdf [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself.

I was making other redirections and find a good method to use in other similar redirections.

```
RewriteRule "^example/CL(.*)USULA DE MUERTE ACCIDENTAL CAD220130535.pdf" https://www.example.com/example-cl/images/example.pdf
```

With this method, this redirection works perfect.